# users with Contribute getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: security, 403

This is something I haven't seen in 4 years. Users in SP Group "Accounting" with Contribute access getting 403b forbidden error. It was working fine until this morning. However, I log in as sp admin and go to the same library and edit the property and SOMETIMES users in accounting group are able to edit (they don't get 403 error). But they are back to 403 error.

Nothing in log. How to go by resolve this issue? (btw, users are not any other readable sp group).

Comment: What is the substatus code in the IIS logs? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737788(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I did not see any 403 error logged in iis log.

Comment: We get the same thing on published pages every now and again, if an Admin goes to the page then the 403 error clears but we don't get much in the IIS logs.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a TMG / Forefront or similar between user and Sharepoint?

We had a lot of such strange issues which boiled down to TMG config.